# Pass Model Along With ViewData Object In Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views

I want to pass Model along with some object stored in ViewData dictionary.
The way I did this is `@Html.Partial("_DataPaging", Model, ViewData['123'])`. But this gives an error that Partial method has some invalid arguments.
How can I pass Model along with some other object which I want to use inside Partial View ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the appropriate overloaded method signature of the `Html.Partial` method is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Partial(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                    string partialViewName,
                                    object model,
                                    ViewDataDictionary viewData);
```

And in your case:

```
@Html.Partial("_DataPaging", Model, ViewData)
```

That means you'll have to extract `ViewData["123"]` manually inside `_DataPaging` partial.

Comment: So why this is not working in case that the return value of ViewData is ViewDataDictionary ?

Comment: Because the method is expecting last parameter of type `ViewDataDictionary`. `ViewData` is indeed `ViewDataDictionary`, `ViewData['123']` is an `object`.